# Tensorfow.js find median of tensor

Tags: statistics, tensorflow.js

I need to find median of a image read as a tensor via tensorflow.js in angular application. Can anyone suggest how to find median in tfjs?

Like -

```
let x = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]);
console.log(x.median());
```

This should print 4.

I tried finding equivalent of tensorflow probability stats in javascript but no luck so far.

Comment: What do you mean by the median of the image ?

Comment: median of pixel values

Comment: Could you please add the formula or an example of computation and the expected value ?

Comment: You can see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The median is the middle number after the series have been arranged. The tensor needs to first sorted. The value at the index `sizeTensor / 2` will be the median value.

```
t= tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]);
tf.topk(t, t.size).values.slice(t.size / 2, 1).print() // will print 4
```

For the above to work with high dimension tensors - images for example, we will need to first reshape to 1d tensor

Given `img` the tensor of an image

```
t = img.reshape([-1])
// do the same as above
```